# How to sideload apps to WinX Mobile

Tags: visual-studio, uwp, windows-10-mobile, sideloading

I have an app that works perfectly on my developer (put in developer mode) phones, now I want to sideload this app to my other phones (put in sideloading mode) but I can't figure out how to do this. I have tried to upload the .appx to the phones but when I try to open them on the phones from the File Explorer nothing happens, maybe it's te wrong way to do it. Any suggestions?

Comment: [Install Universal Windows Apps with the WinAppDeployCmd tool](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/mt203806.aspx).

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer, but it doesn't quiet seem to work. I get a Access denied message when I try to run the `WinAppDeployCmd install -file "Downloads\MyApp.appx" -ip 192.168.0.1 -pin A1B2C3` comand

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sideload apps is a more secure option than Developer mode because you cannot install apps on the device without a trusted certificate.

You should have: devices need to be unlocked for sideloading, certificate assigned to app, signed app package.

1. Settings->Update & Security->For developers->Sideload apps.
2. You can use a runtime provisioning package to import a security certificate:
   Connect the device to your PC through USB. Select the provisioning package that you want to use to provision the device and then drag and drop the file to your device. The Provisioning package installation dialog will appear. You should allow to provision the device. This applies all the runtime settings to the image. Then verify that the runtime settings that were configured in the provisioning package were applied to the device. Here is an official ref: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/dn916107(v=vs.85).aspx#to_apply_a_provisioning_package_to_a_mobile_image
3. With your mobile device tethered to a desktop, click a bundle package from the files system to install the app